# type 'List<Object>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' in type cast

Tags: flutter

the code is like this :

```
class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> questions;
  final int question_index;
  final void Function() answerquestions;
  Quiz(
      {required this.questions,
      required this.answerquestions,
      required this.question_index});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (Column(
      children: [
        Question(questions[question_index]['QuestionText'] as String),
        ...(questions[question_index]['Answers'] as List<String>).map((answer) {
          return Answers(answerquestions, answer);
        }).toList()
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

and the error say is on this line

```
...(questions[question_index]['Answers'] as List<String>).map((answer) {
              return Answers(answerquestions, answer);
            }).toList()
```

and the debug error say:
The relevant error-causing widget was
Quiz

Comment: try replacing `List<String>` with `List<Object>`, Also it would be easy if we could test with `Answers` widget

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Flutter doesn't let you cast directly to `List<String>`.
You have to go two steps, first cast it to a plain `List` (or `List<dynamic>`/`List<Object>`, all essentially the same).
Only in the next step, you cast it again to be of generic type `String`:

```dart
final answers = (questions[question_index]['Answers'] as List)
  .cast<String>()
  .map((answer) {
    // answer is of type String
    ...
  }
  .toList();
```

*Sidenote*: It would be a lot cleaner if you would extract both the question and the answers into local variables outside the return statement. Further it would be a lot easier if you'd extract the parsing from the json / `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` into a different section in your app than this.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final question = Question(questions[question_index]['QuestionText'] as String);
    final answers = ...; // as written above
    return Column(
      children: [
        question,
        answers,
      ],
    );
  }
```